# What are the consequences of revoking a credit card charge made to Origin?

Tags: origin

I have an issue with a purchase I've made via Origin, and after contacting support I feel I'm going to need to raise this as a dispute with my credit card company as my issue is still unresolved. This will obviously result in the payment being revoked from Origin so I'm wondering does anyone have experience with this scenario they are willing to share?

I have already contacted EA customer support, a week ago, 5 days after the purchase. The case is "being worked on", and since I don't use the Origin account at all, I consider to dispute the charge if the time limit for disputing the charge comes up before the answer by Origin arrives.

What are the consequences of revoking a credit card charge made to Origin?

Comment: This question does not belong to gaming.

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 Then neither do 7 out of the 8 questions that are listed as "related" on the sidebar. Could you be more specific - why does it not belong here?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 What law section? Looks on topic to mean, anyway.

Comment: Never mind. Just got some advice from experienced users, they said that @Peter you can ask THAT on Arqade chatrooms.

Comment: Speaking of off-topic, it's unclear (How did you buy? What did you buy? Was it on sale (if so, how much?)? What payment option did you use?)

Comment: Why dispute the payment with your CC when you admit you actually made the transaction, and presumably got what you paid for?

Comment: @aytimothy The details may be a good read and a nice rant about Origin vs Steam, but they are not relevant to the question so I left them out. That's what Origin customer service is for. The payment option was payment by credit card, if that wasn't clear.

Comment: @Peter, it's best practice to go to support and ask for a refund (if you haven't played the game yet) than to get a chargeback, since that would only result in bans; the closing of your account.

Comment: @peter did you buy a game and got it? It doesn't matter if that game satisfies what you want from it or not. If you didn't get the game you paid for, that is a valid reason. If the game is bad, it's your own fault for not informing yourself properly.

Comment: @Peter What did you pay for? What did you get?

Comment: So either you bought a game and didn't like it or bought a game without bothering to read the system requirements and it wouldn't run?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the ramifications of cancelling a credit card charge.  We are not EA, nor Origin, and whatever steps they take are solely at their discretion, and we have no way of knowing what those will be.

Comment: Related to the dispute, in the USA federal law states that banks must give the merchant 15 days to resolve the dispute. It might not be possible to charge back just yet, though don't let this discourage you from doing so if you still want to.

Comment: Just wondering, would it be possible to reword this a bit and migrate it to Money? They know their credit cards better than we do.

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly recommend not doing this. If you didn't receive what you paid for, contact EA. The contact form is at the bottom of [this page](http://help.ea.com/uk/origin/origin/).

Just bear in mind that electronic content is a service, not a physical thing. Specifically, this means **you are not entitled to a refund because the game didn't work on your PC**.

It's difficult to find an actual policy from EA, but I do have anecdotal evidence from Steam (who, if anything, are likely to be more lenient than Origin). In cases where a user disputed a payment, their Steam account was blocked during the arbitration. There is no reason to expect Origin to behave differently.

Remember, from their point of view, you bought something, promised to pay them and refused to pay. I can't think of any business in the world that would tolerate that.

Comment: Aww yiss, 15k rep.

Comment: It's not just about the business accepting it, it is also a legal question, since if you buy a game on a gaming platform (or any other sort of online shop), a contract is created between you and the offering business, in which the business promisses to serve you with the game and you promiss to pay a certain amount of money. If you redraw your payment you offend against that contract.

Comment: While this is decent advice, it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Peter Then dispute the charges and answer your own question when it happens. I can't see the future, I'm not affiliated with Origin and the research I did couldn't find a case of this happening. I explained what they could do and what they were likely to do from the information I had.

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly recommend against doing that. EA actually have pretty good refund policy, and if you didn't like what you recently bought you should ask for a refund rather than going such a radical way.

Take a look at their article http://help.ea.com/en/article/origin-eu-returns-and-cancellations/
Even if you don't fit into that group, you should contact their customer service (which is pretty good actually) and ask for refund.